# Pi 4 will not boot unless hold raspberry key

Tags: pi-4

If I just start pi4 the video output goes blank right after white screen. if I repeated push raspberry key on keyboard it will boot.
Any ideas?

Comment: Is the raspberry key the only key that does this? What are the "Operating System" and "Kernel" fields of `hostnamectl`?

Comment: It is also possible that your SPI EEPROM has become corrupted. To check, **remove the SD card**, disconnect the device from power, then reconnect it. If the green LED does not flash, you will need to reprogram the EEPROM: https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/ and scroll down to "Recovery".